# Log appearing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

What's wrong with this Error?

> [2019-08-24 01:10:01] local.ERROR: The Process class relies on
>   proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\LogicException(code: 0): The
>   Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP
>   installation. at
>   /home/comscms/domains/comscms.ir/video_sharing/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:143)
>   [stacktrace]

Comment: You probably using a shared host and I guess your shared host has explicitly disabled proc_open on their PHP instance you can try contact them to fix the issue for you.

Comment: enable proc_open functionIn php.ini file